# Android listView visualizar listViewItem

Tags: android

Tenho uma listView que parte da linha só é exibida quando expandida. O problema é que quando a linha é expandida próximo a parte inferior da tela não dá para ver todos itens.

Como faço para saber se os itens expandidos estão visíveis e caso não estejam fazer o scroll na listView ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está definindo o height da lista como wrap_content?

Comment: Os três layouts como height wrap-content.

Comment: Isso é uma ListView ou uma ExpandableListView?

Comment: Uma ListView e o item é um RelativeLayout

Comment: Recomendo usar ExpandableListView que foi feito especificamente para ser uma lista com itens expandíveis.

Comment: Consegui resolver com listView.smoothScrollToPosition(item) - Obrigado!